# Regex how to capture string up to a character only when another character exists

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I would like to use regex to capture everything in a string up to a colon followed by a space, `:` OR a comma followed by a space, `,` but only using the comma as a condition if the colon with a space can be found in the string. In other words, if there is no `:`, I do not want to capture anything. If there is `:` in the string, I want to capture everything up until it OR up until a `,` if the `,` comes before the `:`.

I am trying with

```
/(?:(?!: )[^])*/g
```

and

```
/(?:(?!: )[^])*/g
```

Some example text:

Here I want to capture only `DeBary`:

```
DeBary, OH: Suddenly on Thursday, June 16, 2011 at the age of 78.
```

Here I want to capture only `DeBary`:

```
DeBary: Suddenly on Thursday, June 16, 2011 at the age of 78.
```

Here I want to capture nothing:

```
Suddenly on Thursday, June 16, 2011 at the age of 78.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work.

```
 # (?s)^(?=.*:[ ]).*?(?=[,:][ ])

 (?s)               # Dot-all modifier     
 ^                  # BOS
 (?= .* : [ ] )     # Lookahead for colon then space 
 .*?                # Consume minimal any chars up until
 (?= [,:] [ ] )     # Lookahead, Comma or colon, then whitespace
```

Or, it could be done without the final lookahead.

```
 # (?s)^(?=.*:[ ])[^,:]*

 (?s)               # Dot-all modifier     
 ^                  # BOS
 (?= .* : [ ] )     # Lookahead for colon then space 
 [^,:]*             # Consume non comma nor colon
```

Answer (score 1):

As above, though if you want to *capture* the matching substring, then you need a capturing, not a non-capturing group, with the quantifier `+` *within* the group:

`^([^,:]+)(?=.*?:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with lookahead:

```
^(?:[^,:])+(?=.*?:)
```

[Regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lT5sK2/1)

`(?:[^,:])+` captures a sequence of characters that aren't commas or colons.

`(?=.*?:)` requires that this match is followed by any any characters and then a colon somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should capture what you want:

```
^([^\n,:]+)(?=.*:)
```

Example:

**http://regex101.com/r/vE0eP4/1**

[image: ^[^\n,:]+(?=.*:)]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without lookahead:

```
^(.*?)(?:, .*: |: )
```

This assumes the implementation gives leftmost alternations precedence, which most do.